# Polynomial at least one root between 0 and 1

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

$p(x)=a_0+a_1x+...a_nx^n$ with $$a_0+\frac{a_1}2+ \cdots +\frac{a_n}{n+1}=0$$
Heuristically, I feel like this should have at least one root between 0 and 1, because at least one of the coefficients will have a different sign than the others making the graph of the function have a kink. 
but I am very unsure where to start.